# How can I add the items from a listview to a listbox?

Tags: listview, listbox, addition

I want to create a receipt for items in my list view in c# which has 4 columns.
The list view: [image]

I want to add the items from that view to a listbox in order to generate a receipt. Is my approach even correct? I honestly don't have any idea how to make the list view items into a receipt.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery Grid](http://jquerygrid.net/). It is easy to View and add the columns..

In this `onloadCompleteFunction` you can multiply the columns and it will show the results in other columns..